# How to display total in footer using knockout js

Tags: asp.net, knockout.js

I have just recently started using knockout js and need to display total of deductedfee at the bottom of table usign knockoutjs. Currenlty the code written does not display total in UI but all the values are binded properly.

```
 function GetDeviceFee() {           
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "DeviceFee.aspx/GetDeviceFeeDetails",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response != undefined && response != '') {
                    var data = JSON.parse(response.d);
          //Code to calculate total
                     var total = ko.pureComputed(function () {
                            var total = 0;
                            for (var p = 0; p < data.length; p++) {
                                total += data[p].DeductedFee;
                            }
                            return total;
                        });
                        alert(total);
   //Verifying the total value using alert
                        ko.applyBindings({
                            rows: data
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        document.getElementById("divDeviceFee").html("No historical data avaible.")
            .css({ 'height': 300, 'paddingLeft': 10, 'paddingRight': 10 });
                    }
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        }
```

When I try to verify the value of total using alert: the following message is displayed,

```
function g(){if(0<arguments.length){if("function"===typeof C)C.apply(d,arguments);else throw Error("Cannot write a value to a ko.computed unless you specify a 'write' option. If you wish to read the current value, don't pass any parameters.");
return this}a.k.Ob(g);(r||s&&f())&&l();return n}
```

Data is binded in table as follows:

```
<td valign="middle" align="left" data-bind="text: total">
                            </td>
```

Found many solutions in net to display total using knouckoutjs but nothing seems working for me. I know I have done something wrong, but not able to analyze the issue.Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all wrong.

- Don't create computed values in Ajax success callbacks. This makes no sense.
- Don't aggregate Ajax responses in Ajax success callbacks. It's better to assign the result to an observable and do calculations and aggregations in knockout.
- Don't modify the view from inside the view model. No calling `document.getElementById`, no setting CSS values, no `ko.applyBindings`, no jQuery (except utility functions that don't modify the document, like Ajax). The view must depend on the view model, not the other way around.
- jQuery parses JSON responses for you automatically, no need to interfere.
- Last but not least: Can you explain why you POST to an API method that is called `Get...`?

Better:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.rows = ko.observableArray();
    self.totalDeductedFee = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        var total = 0;
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.rows(), function (row) {
            total += row.DeductedFee;
        });
        return total;
    });
    self.hasHistoricalData = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        return self.rows().length > 0;
    });
    self.getDeviceFeeDetails = function () {
        self.rows.removeAll();
        return $.get("DeviceFee.aspx/GetDeviceFeeDetails").done(function (response) {
            if (response.d && response.d.length) self.rows(response.d);
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("GetDeviceFeeDetails failed: " + errorThrown);
        });
    };
}

var vm = new ViewModel();
vm.getDeviceFeeDetails();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

and

```html
<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: rows">
    <!-- ... show the row -->
  </tbody>
</table>

<!-- ko if: hasHistoricalData -->
<div>Total deducted fee: <span data-bind="text: totalDeductedFee"></span></div>
<!-- /ko -->

<!-- ko ifnot: hasHistoricalData -->
<div>No historical data avaible.</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: may be a typo in ajax `.done` & `purecomputed` it should be `self.rows` . nice and neat answer

Comment: @tomalak : Thanks for the reply.  Webmethod call was only working when I tried with post.

Comment: I see. Then you should modify the web method to accept `GET`. `POST` requests should be reserved for sending new data to the server.

Answer (score 1):

What I can see is you're applying bindings on the "data" object but the value of "total" is not returned to any of the property in the "data" object.

Which means value of "total" is not going back in "data" object which is binded.

See an example below and try to achieve something like this-

```
// This is a simple *viewmodel* - JavaScript that defines the data and behavior of your UI
function AppViewModel() {
    this.firstName = ko.observable("Bert");
    this.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");

    this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();    
    }, this);
}

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
<p>Full name: <strong data-bind="text: fullName"></strong></p>
```